# Connect to Azure SQL Database using access token in .NET Core without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

I am working on a .NET Core application. Can I connect to an Azure SQL database using an access token without adding Entity Framework to my application?

There are a lot of articles online which show the connection using Entity Framework (example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can the use [System.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/) NuGet package, specifically [SqlConnection.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.accesstoken).